# asp.net 3.5 url rerouting in VB ASP.net3.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, reroute

i want my user www.xyz.com/UserName

to move it to www.xyz.com/default.aspx where i can get username

is there any sample of vb

this is good sample http://cstruter.com/blog/276 but it is C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/